# reutilizar código heredando de un fichero

Tags: php, sql

Tengo varios ficheros que tienen la misma estructura,

```
<?PHP

// Conectamos con la base de datos.
// LOCAL
$bd_host = "localhost"; 
$bd_usuario = "root"; 
$bd_password = ""; 
$bd_base = "carrot";


$conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password); 
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$bd_base);

// Hacemos la consulta que en ese momento me interesa. POR EJEMPLO la siguiente
$campo1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['Campo1']);
$campo2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['Campo2']);
$consulta = "
    INSERT INTO propuesta(campo1, campo2)
    VALUES ('$campo1', '$campo2')
";

// Y finalmente lo ejecuto.

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
```

¿Hay alguna manera de que esto sea una clase y heredarlo, de manera que no tenga que poner este código cada vez? Simplemente lo llame (de nombre por ejemplo conexion) y luego ya haga yo aquello que me interese en cada caso.

Comment: Yo simplemente tengo 2 funciones en un fichero `conexion.php` cada una con sus parametros, y si necesito hacer la conexion simplemente:  `include "conexion.php";` y luego pues vas llamando a cada funcion segun lo que necesites

Answer (score 1):

lo que yo haría es crear dos ficheros uno donde se envían las consultas y otro donde se hace la conexión a la base de datos; por ejemplo creamos un fichero que se llame conexion.php y otro que se llame consultas.php

**Conexion.php**

```
<?PHP
//Clase para la conexion con las bases de datos
class conexion{
     var $link;

     //Metodo constructor
     function conexion(){
        $bd_host = "localhost"; 
        $bd_usuario = "root"; 
        $bd_password = ""; 
        $bd_base = "carrot";
        $this->link=mysqli_connect($serv_db,$usu_db,$pass_db,$bd_base);
     }


     //Otros metodos
     function query($consulta){
        return mysqli_query($this->link, $consulta) or
        die(mysqli_error($this->link));
     }
}
```

**Consultas.php**

```
<?PHP
include("Conexion.php");
$conex=new Conexion();
$campo1="valor1";
$campo2="valor2";
$consulta = "INSERT INTO propuesta(campo1, campo2) VALUES ('$campo1', '$campo2')";
$resultado = $conex->query($consulta);
```

Comment: Buenas he cogido tu código tal cual pero al hacerlo así los valores almacenados en las variables $campo1 y $campo2 no me los coge y por lo tanto se genera una nueva fila en mi BD pero vacía. :S

Comment: tienes que definir las variables 
`
 $campo1="valor1";
 $campo2="valor2";
 $consulta = "
  INSERT INTO propuesta(campo1, campo2)
  VALUES ('$campo1', '$campo2')
 ";` si no debe ser que lo esta tomando como multilinea entonces coloca el insert en una sola linea

Comment: @NEA pues tu código tampoco define esas variables. La idea es que adaptes el código que te muestran a tus necesidades

Comment: @Alfabravo disculpa eso me lo dejé aquí, ahora lo añado. En el original si que está definido.

Comment: @junior hice lo de una sola linea y támpoco, cuando tenía toda el proceso de conexión en este mismo fichero si que iba, no entiendo que puede ser el causante la verdad

Comment: Revisen logs, usen `die()` para ver qué pasa con la ejecución de la consulta

Comment: hay lo edito como dice @Alfabravo en el fichero Conexion.php